# Moving a 2D physics body on a parabolic path with initial impulse in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics, gravity

**What I have:**

A projectile in Unity 5 2D, affected by gravity, that I want to move from point A to point B with initial impulse on a parabolic path

**What I know:**

- The 2D coordinates of a random starting position (A)
- The 2D coordinates of a random target position (B)
- The time (X) I want the body to reach the target position after

**What I want to know:**

- The initial impulse (as in unity applyforce with forcemode impulse) that I have to apply to the body onetime in order for it to reach the desired position B after X time.

**Notes:**

- It is a 2D world using Unity 2D physics
- The two positions A and B are totally random and may or may NOT be at equal heights (y coordinates)
- I want to apply the impulse one time only when spawning the projectile
- The projectile does NOT have any other forces affecting him other than GRAVITY (for the current problem lets assume that it always with magnitude 9.8 pointed down)

Here is a (bad) drawing of what I want :D
[image]

Thanks upfront guys!

Answer (score 4):

Let's solve a few simpler problems. Our goal is to find an initial velocity for the particle, instead of an "impulse", because we'll achieve better control this way.

First, consider how we would solve this without Unity physics. A particle's position as a function of time depends on its initial position, velocity and acceleration. The same equations apply regardless of how many dimensions you have. This equation is:

`current_position = 1/2 * acceleration * time^2 + velocity * time + starting_position`

Let `current_position` be our desired destination, `time` be the duration of travel you choose, and the `starting_position` to be the starting position of the particle.

In the x-dimension, there is no acceleration. Let `X_0` be our starting X position, `X_1` be our destination, and `T` be the duration of time we want to spend getting to that destination. We want to find `v_x`, or the velocity in the x-dimension. For ease of interpretation, I've marked all the constants in uppercase and the variable in lowercase.

1. `X_1 = v_x*T + X_0`
2. `v_x = (X_1-X_0)/T`

In the y-dimension, we have gravity of some kind. So let's incorporate that as our acceleration:

1. `Y_1 = 0.5*G*T*T + v_y*T + Y_0`
2. `v_y = (Y_1 - Y_0 - 0.5*G*T*T)/T`

Now that you have `v_x` and `v_y`, just set the velocity:

```
rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(v_x, v_y);
```

Since different objects have different mass, you don't want to try to calculate an impulse. Just set the velocity to what you want in the frame when the object is spawned.

This runs contrary to advice you might find elsewhere on the Internet, but **try it first** before doing something more complicated.

Some important notes:

- Physics processing in Unity isn't stable: you might get different results on different platforms, especially between different mobile devices. If there is performance pressure, there may be fewer physics evaluations and therefore incorrect results. This is generally not a problem with 2D physics.
- You may experience an issue with the scale of gravity, depending on your version and what other settings you have.

Answer (score 3):

The formulas of position of a projectile influenced only by gravity are these:

```
x = x0 + v_x0*t
y = y0 + v_y0*t + 0.5*g*t^2
```

so, to know the starting velocity, with some basic calculations:

```
v_x0 = (x-x0)/t
v_y0 = (y-y0)/t + 0.5*g*t^2/t = (y-y0)/t - 4.9*t
```

Now, in order to add this startin velocity by using `AddForce`, we could have used `ForceMode.VelocityChange`, but this mode is only available for 3D rigidbodies, so we need to use the `ForceMode.Impulse` and multiplying the force by the mass of the object:

```
RigidBody2D rigid = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
rigid.AddForce(new Vector2 (v_x0, v_y0) * rigid.mass, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

and that's it.

Of course you can just set the velocity of the rigid body directly instead of using `AddForce`.